# Can I start a declarative sentence with "What"?

Tags: questions, what

I would like to write something like, "What makes you happy will make you insane."  I know that I can rewrite this as, "The thing that makes you happy will make you insane," but I like the balance of the sentence's structure, and "the thing" comes across awkwardly in this case.

I have reviewed other posts on the Stack Exchange website to see if there is any specific rule against beginning with "what"--looking specifically at posts related to interrogatives--but I have been unable to find a rule against it. I'm familiar with famous quotes that use declarative statements and that begin with "what," but I didn't want to rely on these as proof of grammatical correctness.

So, is it grammatically permissible to begin a declarative sentence with the word "what" or should I only use it in a question? If it is permissible, is there a rule that demonstrates this is okay?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. You can start a sentence with what as you have done: whatever makes you happy.

Comment: A famous concept is often phrased as "What doesn't kill you makes you stronger."  Although it is also phrased beginning with "That which..." or "Whatever..." instead, the idea is the same.

Comment: _What_ (as most other interrogatives in English) is both an interrogative pronoun/determinative and a relative one. Consider, “I don't know what you mean”, where it is also used in a non-interrogative context.

Comment: No: in "I don't know what you mean", the expression "what you mean" is an interrogative content clause (embedded question). The meaning is "I don't know the answer to the question 'What do you mean?"'

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In case you didn't get pinged by Bill's comment, in the phrase "I don't know what you mean", the string "what you mean" is indeed an interrogative clause (in any plausible interpretation of the sentence, that is). :-)

Comment: @BillJ Note that I said a non-interrogative _content_, not a non-interrogative clause. The sentence as a whole is not a question, which is what the question here asked about.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, thank you for the response and for citing the rules behind it. If you will provide as an answer, I'd be happy to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

A famous example from Twilight of the Idols, by Friedrich Nietzsche, and the translations by Walter Kaufmann and R.J. Hollingdale:

- Out of life's school of war: What does not destroy me, makes me
  stronger.

Some not-too-famous examples from In the Midst of Life: Tales of Soldiers and Civilians, by Ambrose Bierce

- What he heard was the ticking of his watch.
- What you call dying is simply the last pain—there is really no such
  thing as dying.
- What he saw, in the shadow under his bed, was two small points of
  light, apparently about an inch apart...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, definitely you can use it this way. And here's another type of example: in an exclamatory way. "What a fool I was to believe I could eat that third pizza!" or "What a blessing, to be born in Virginia!"

Comment: He needs a declarative sentence beginning with 'What', not an exclamatory one.

Comment: That part of the question had already been answered. I thought it might help some people to add this little bit. Apparently you don't see it that way. Oh well. What a shame.